# Wrap each first letter of each word in span tag - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, word-wrap

I need to wrap each first letter of each word from line with specific css class "eachword" into "span" html tag - using the javascript.
Meanwhile I have good worked script, except one issue, the script converts special characters like "&" into html format.
So, here's what I have right now:

Before script is applied:

```
<a class="eachword" href="#">Models & Brands</a>
```

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function()
{
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("eachword");

    for( var i=0; i<elements.length; i++)
    {
        elements[i].innerHTML = elements[i].innerHTML.replace(/\b([a-z])([a-z]+)?\b/gim, "<span class='firstletter'>$1</span>$2");
    }
}
</script>
```

Result:

```
<a class="eachword" href="#"><span class="firstletter">Models &<span class="firstletter">a</span>mp; <span class="firstletter">Brands</span></a>
```

And I need this result:

```
<a class="eachword" href="#"><span class="firstletter">Models <span class="firstletter">& </span><span class="firstletter">Brands</span></a>
```

In "head" tag, I also have jQuery 1.7.2 included.

So, the question is, what's wrong with the code, where did I make mistake? Thanks for attention, hope for your help!

Comment: You said you need this result and it is no way matching what you asked... Confusing... What do you have and what do you need?

Comment: There was no semicolons at the end of statements in the JS. Also, why include jQuery if you're not using it?

Comment: @ilovecode I'm using jQuery, I mentioned it, so if someone's gonna provide alternative with jQuery - to know that I'm already using it.

Comment: @PraveenKumar After the script is applied I have this result "Models &AMP; Brands", and I need "&" instead "&AMP;".

Comment: Ah, that could be done by a simple replace! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work for me, may be a bit clumsy though

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    // For each of the eachword class
    $("a.eachword").each(function()
    {
        // Get the string (html) and split it by " " (like PHP's explode)
        var self         = $(this);
        var theText      = self.html();
        var theTextArray = theText.split(" ");

        // Cycle them
        for (var i = 0; i < theTextArray.length; i++)
        {
            // Get this particular word and split it into individual letters
            var thisWord      = theTextArray[i];
            var thisWordArray = thisWord.split("");

            // Wrap the first letter if it is not a HTML char code
            if (thisWordArray[0] != "&")
            {
                thisWordArray[0]  = "<span class='firstletter'>"+thisWordArray[0]+"</span>";
            }

            // Stitch the letters back up
            theTextArray[i] = thisWordArray.join("");
        }

        // Join the original string back up
        var result = theTextArray.join(" ");

        self.html( result );
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SFgXZ/

Comment: That's just amazing, thank you very much @ilovecode - works perfectly!

Comment: No worries mate, was actually a problem I wanted to solve for myself as well!

Comment: Awesome! Any way to target only specific letters? Like all capital H's or Capital H or a specific word?

Answer (score 3):

In vanilla JS, a bit faster I think:

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    var words = a[i].innerHTML.split(" ");

    for (j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
        if(words[j][0] != "&") {
            words[j] = "<span class='firstletter'>" + words[j][0] + "</span>" + words[j].substring(1);
        }
    }

    a[i].innerHTML=words.join(" ");
}
```

The more modern way:

```
var anchors = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("a"));
anchors.forEach(a => {
  a.innerHTML =
    a.textContent
    .split(' ')
    .map(word => {
      if (word[0] != '&') {
        return `<span class="firstletter">${word[0]}</span>${word.substring(1)}`;
      } else {
        return word;
      }
    })
    .join(' ');
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gilles_1007/3666n/).