# How to wrap each word in a span

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to have it so when I click on a word, it'll be marked out with a black background. Right now, I am wrapping each word in a sentence in its own span, but I would like to create a span for each word in a block of text. Any ideas on how to go about doing that?

Here is my code right now

```
document.querySelectorAll('span').forEach(span=> 
    span.onclick = () => {
    span.style.background = '#000';
})
```

HTML

```
<span>these </span>
<span>are </span>
<span>some </span>
<span>words </span>
<span>for </span>
<span>a </span>
<span>test </span>
```

Comment: Did you try and use your favorite search engine and search "wrap each word in span JavaScript"?

Comment: Yeah I did, they were mostly jquery answers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15602535 https://stackoverflow.com/a/50135988 https://stackoverflow.com/a/66380709 https://stackoverflow.com/a/24487987 https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557908

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
const text = "These are some words for a test";
 
text.split(' ').forEach(word => {                  // loop over every word
  const element = document.createElement("span");  // create element "span"
  element.innerText = word;                        // set its content to word
  element.onclick = () =>                          // onclick handler
    element.style.background = '#000';             // action
  document.body.appendChild(element);              // add element to dom
});
```

```css
span {
  color: orange;
  margin-left: 3px;
}
```